# What am I doing wrong with the following try, throw and catch exception handlers in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code that works without using throw however when I use the throw keyword it doesn't return the appropriate message. What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

I am deliberately calling the function `addme` as opposed to `addMe` as I want to catch the error message.

**Code - That works without using `throw`**

```
function addMe() {
        var a = 1;
        var b = 2;
        return a+b;
    }

    try {
        addme();
    }


    catch (err) {
        document.write(err.name + " " + err.message);
    }
```

**Code - That does not work**

```
function addMe() {
        var a = 1;
        var b = 2;
        return a+b;
    }

    try {
        addme();
        throw "error 1";
    }

    catch(err) {
        if(err ==  "error 1") {
            document.write("This is a custom message for error 1");
        }
    }
```

Comment: two typos i see. Your function name is `addMe`, but when you call it, you call `addme` (no capital M). Also, you throw `error 1` (with space) and check to see if it equals `error1` (no space)

Comment: @jackwanders - Sorry I amended my post with the appropriate spacing between `error` and `1`. I am deliberately calling the function `addme` as opposed to `addMe` as I want to catch the error.

Comment: If you do that, the error caught will not be "error 1", but rather `ReferenceError: addme is not defined`. Your `throw` statement does not mean "in case of any error, throw this message", it means "if you reach this line of code, throw this error". Your code never reaches the `throw` statement because calling the undefined function throws a different error first

Comment: @jackwanders - That makes sense. The examples I have been reading don't explicitly state that using `throw` does not mean "display this error message". I don't quite follow what you mean by "if you reach this line of code, throw this error"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`addme` is undefined, so you never reach your `throw` statement. (Specifically, a [`ReferenceError`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError) is thrown first when you call `addme` rather than `addMe`)

The key thing to remember is the program is read from the top down - until you inject a `GOTO` (an error, calling a function, returning from a function, etc.) that sends you somewhere else.  Once you [`GOTO Raptor`](http://xkcd.com/292/) the lines beneath that line are not guaranteed to be called.

```
try {
    addme(); // Reference Error Thrown - go to catch statement
    throw "error 1"; // We never get here
}

catch(err) {
    // Never true - err is always a ReferenceError.
    if(err ==  "error 1") {
        document.write("This is a custom message for error 1");
    }
```

To deal with any type of error you can check `err instanceof TYPE_OF_ERROR`:

```
catch(err) {
    if(err instanceof ReferenceError) {
        document.write("This is a custom message for ReferenceErrors");
    }
}
```

(And please remember, [a string is not an error](http://www.devthought.com/2011/12/22/a-string-is-not-an-error/))

Comment: I have amended my question. I am purposely calling the function `addme` as I want to catch the error and then display the custom message as opposed to `ReferenceError`

Comment: Can you elaborate on hat you mean by "so you never reach your throw statement"? When would you reach `throw`?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey - I gave it a shot - let me know if it helps.

Comment: That helps but I don't quite follow when `throw` would be reached.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey - it *will **never*** be reached - that's the point - the JavaScript interpreter reads line one: `try`.  That succeeds.  Then it reads line 2: `addme`.  It can't find any definition for `addme` and so it *stops reading line by line* and checks to see if it is in a `try` block.  It is, so it goes to the `catch` block (line 6) and passes it the error that was created at line 2.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Sorry for being a n00b but yes that example does help but what I am wanting to understand is assuming I had called the function `addMe()`, would it then reach `throw`. If it does, what does that mean exactly?. Is it considered an error?

Comment: I amended my code to `addMe()` and it does then reach `throw` however why does it then get called by `catch` when it is not an error? Is `throw` not used for exception handling?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13199/discussion-between-sean-vieira-and-peanutsmonkey)

Comment: That's what is tripping me up. What do you mean by "create" and "throw"? My understanding is that I use `try` to capture the error and then to use `catch` to return the error message. Where does `throw` fit in the picture?